# What are .nsh files? Can't find any docs for it

Tags: file

I recently saw a .nsh file for the first time.
What is it? I can't find any docs regarding this language.
Does anyone know a good place to learn about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an installer file used by NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System), a program used for creating Windows installers; saves header information that can be included across all .NSI installer scripts; helps setup common environment conditions for an installation.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks to you, i looked for docs about Nsis and found them [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs)